# Having trouble calling the MD5 function (Obejctive-C, iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, function, md5

I tried to use MD5 encryption for the iPhone app I'm creating. I created an md5.m file with the following code (copied from StackOverflow):

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

NSString* md5( NSString *str ) {
  const char *cStr = [str UTF8String];
  unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

  CC_MD5( cStr, strlen(cStr), result );

  return [[NSString
      stringWithFormat:@"%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
      result[0], result[1],
      result[2], result[3],
      result[4], result[5],
      result[6], result[7],
      result[8], result[9],
      result[10], result[11],
      result[12], result[13],
      result[14], result[15]
      ] lowercaseString];
}
```

I then tried to call the function (in a different .m file) using:

```
NSString *digest = md5(@"password");
```

But for some reason I keep on getting the error "Expected expression before 'mad5'"... What have I don't wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have placed `NSString* md5( NSString *str );` in the header file that corresponds to the implementation file (.m). Also, make sure you import that header file into the class that will be using that function using `#import TestClass.h`.

This has been tested:

TestClass.h

```
@interface TestClass : NSObject { }

NSString* md5 (NSString* str);

@end
```

TestClass.m

```
#import "TestClass.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

@implementation TestClass

    NSString* md5( NSString *str )
    {
      const char *cStr = [str UTF8String];
      unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

      CC_MD5( cStr, strlen(cStr), result );

      return [[NSString
          stringWithFormat:@"%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
          result[0], result[1],
          result[2], result[3],
          result[4], result[5],
          result[6], result[7],
          result[8], result[9],
          result[10], result[11],
          result[12], result[13],
          result[14], result[15]
          ] lowercaseString];
    }

@end
```

UsingClass.m

```
-(void)useMD5
{
    NSString *digest = md5(@"password");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did the #import, however my headerfile setup is a bit different: - (NSString *)md5Return: (NSString *) str;

Comment: See my edited post. The method in the .h should always match the method in the .m file.

Answer (score 1):

If I just take your code and paste it into a simple Foundation tool, everything compiles and runs.

If you copy/pasted your error, then 'mad5' means you misspelled 'md5'.

If you're getting an error regarding the expression, it probably means you have a syntax error higher up in your code and the line you're pasting here is just the first one the compiler is able to put an error on.

Comment: I didn't misspel 'md5', that was an actual typo. Thanks for the third suggestion, I'm looking for the syntax error higher-up now. However the whole program ran without any error before I added the md5 stuff